# Add chat to the apps

Tags: feature-request, chat, android-app, ios-app

I love to use Stack Overflow chat. I usually have a iPad or phone nearby, and would like to see the app support the chat rooms, to be more convenient.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191334/310078